# compare all elements of arraylist with first element

Tags: java, arraylist

```
 int odo_str=o.getSpans();
ArrayList<integer> newlist = new ArrayList<integer>();
 newlist.add(odo_str);
```

In an arraylist how to compare all elements with first element in the arraylist,if it is greater than first element then i want to store them in one array,if elements are less than first element then want to store them in another arraylist.how to do it.thanks.

Comment: You've described exactly what you need to do in code, in words. If we could see an attempt at that, we could help out.

Comment: Okay ,tried debugging my list contains 20000,23444,345545,565454,5654,4565,........

Comment: Obviously you will need to use some form of a `loop` with `if-else` inside it.  You also will need to decide what to do with elements that are **equal** to the 1st one.

Comment: i got that basic idea ,could you please try it pro-grammatically.bcz i am not able to  do it. so posted here for experts suggestion..

Comment: Note*: StackOverflow is not the place to come to have code written for you, it is a place to come for help with your own code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some help:

To get the first element in the ArrayList:

```
<T> firstElement = ArrayList<T>.get(0);
```

To iterate through an ArrayList:

```
for (T element : yourArrayList) { //do things }
```

Conditional example:

```
if (element > firstElement) { //do things }
```

Storing item in array:

```
yourArray[index] = element;
```

Storing item in ArrayList:

```
yourOtherArrayList.add(element);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
public class Main {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<Integer> myList = Arrays.asList(12,34,45,23,45,7,68,4,345,56,67,4,999,454,6,76,0);
            Iterator<Integer> iter = myList.iterator();
            List<Integer> lessList = new ArrayList<Integer>(), biggerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Integer firstItem = iter.next();
            while (iter.hasNext()) {
                Integer currElement = iter.next();
                if (firstItem.compareTo(currElement) > -1) {
                    lessList.add(currElement);
                } else {
                    biggerList.add(currElement);
                }
            }

            System.out.println(lessList.toString());
            System.out.println(biggerList.toString());
        }

    }
```

This print:

[7, 4, 4, 6, 0]

[34, 45, 23, 45, 68, 345, 56, 67, 999, 454, 76]